# Are Win32 windows thread safe?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'd like to create a window on one thread, and then have that HWND migrate to one of any number of threads on which it will execute. My program will have multiple such windows. Is this possible or was the Win32 API not designed for this?

Comment: So you'd like to create something on one thread and then delete it on another and you don't see a problem with that idea?

Comment: @AJG: It's no problem for `new`/`delete`. Entirely reasonable to wonder about other resources.

Comment: @MSalters: Depends on implementation but there was no mention of heap allocation. Was just bringing it up in case it was overlooked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The thread that a window uses for its message loop (what you refer to as "executing on") is defined at the time the window is created. You can create multiple threads and start message loops from them (and thus create windows on them), but this is generally regarded as dangerous.

Comment: Some guy came along and downvoted everything with a down arrow on this page, I tried to undo it

Comment: Not the downvoter here, but I would like to know: How/why is using multiple GUI threads 'dangerous'? It's perhaps an advanced practice - not something you need to do in an average Hello World or simple dialog app, but not dangerous that I know of. It's common practice in many complex apps (Explorer, IE, likely office too).

Comment: @BrendanMcK: "Dangerous" might not have been the best word choice here, but I meant it in the sense that you must be careful with how you use it.

Comment: @Adam; got it - so Dangerous in the sense that even regular multi-threading is full of potential pitfalls for those unfamiliar with the area. Anyhow, just wanted to clarify that having multiple GUI threads is perfectly valid and supported use of Win32 API.

Comment: @BrendanMcK: Yes; admittedly, I come from dealing with .NET developers, where the ease of creating both GUI applications and additional threads leads people to a false sense of security when dealing with the combination of the two.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, to a certain extent.

You can send and post messages to an HWND from any thread.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Attempting to configure the UI (e.g. add controls) from another thread will end badly.  However, if you send your window a message, you can be sure that the message will be processed on the creating thread.

Comment: This is the most correct answer - Win32 is actually the most lenient of the UI frameworks with regard to cross-thread access, win32k.sys tries to make everything work. However, it's still a better idea to pretend you don't know this, and operate as if objects were thread affinitized

Comment: Yes.  "Mostly works" isn't a description I like to have associated with anything that I write :).  

It seems that if you're not real strict on Send/Posting messages (or their 21st century counterparts) weird stuff sometimes just happens.

Comment: This is the better answer, because sending messages was what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 3):

There are two important calls that [must be called from the same thread](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/90975): `CreateWindow` and `GetMessage` (or their respective equivalents). Your solution wouldn't, so it's wrong.

You may call `PostMessage` in any thread. `SendMessage` is somewhat dangerous because it blocks in cross-thread scenario's, and could deadlock.

Comment: I had a situation today where some code on a worker thread called SendMessage from a critical section and deadlocked. Having wasted an hour looking at it, I thought it more prudent to just put the processing onto the UI thread and PostMessage my instruction across.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no concurrency checking on those calls.